# Create SSRS Subscriptions from XML File with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell, reporting-services

I am trying to read an XML file that contains SSRS subscriptions from SQL 2005 and create a new subscription on SQL 2019. I've tried the ReportingServicesTools but couldn't get it to work. I did use the Get-RsSubscription and Export-RsSubscriptionXml to get the 2005 subscriptions into an XML file.

I've got my script to read the XML file, but I get an error when I try to create a subscription.

It only errors on the CreateSubscription. The values show for each variable in the foreach.

[image]

I feel like I'm so close, and I really don't want to manually re-create hundreds of subscriptions. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
Cannot convert argument "ExtensionSettings", with value: "Obj", for "CreateSubscription" to type 
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3tserver_ReportService2010_asmx.ExtensionSettings": "Cannot convert the 
"System.Xml.XmlElement" value of type "System.Xml.XmlElement#http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04#Obj" to type 
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3tserver_ReportService2010_asmx.ExtensionSettings"."
At line:38 char:1
+ $Proxy.CreateSubscription($Report_Path, $DeliverySettings, $Descripti ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Here is the **Powershell** I've made so far.

```
[XML]$userfile = Get-Content "E:\Test_File.xml" 

$Subscriptions = $userfile.Objs.Obj.MS 

 foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions )
            {
              #S
                 $Report = $sub.S | Where-Object {$_.N -EQ 'Report'} |foreach {$_.'#text'} 
                 $Report

                 $Report_Path = $sub.S | Where-Object {$_.N -EQ 'Path'} |foreach {$_.'#text'} 
                 $Report_Path

                 $Description = $sub.S | Where-Object {$_.N -EQ 'Description'} |foreach {$_.'#text'} 
                 $Description

                 $EventType = $sub.S | Where-Object {$_.N -EQ 'EventType'} |foreach {$_.'#text'} 
                 $EventType

                 $MatchData = $sub.S | Where-Object {$_.N -EQ 'MatchData'} |foreach {$_.'#text'} 
                 $MatchData

              #Obj
     
                 $DeliverySettings = $sub.Obj | Where-Object {$_.N -EQ 'DeliverySettings'} 
                 $DeliverySettings

                 $Values = $sub.Obj | Where-Object {$_.N -EQ 'Values'}
                 $Values

} 


$ReportServerUri = 'http://vsql2019test/reportserver'
$Proxy = New-RSWebServiceProxy -ReportServerUri $ReportServerUri 


$Proxy.CreateSubscription($Report_Path, $DeliverySettings, $Description, $EventType, $MatchData, $Values)
```

And here is the **XML** file I'm reading:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <MS>
      <S N="EventType">TimedSubscription</S>
      <S N="SubscriptionID">81036c7a-1749-4539-ade8-004e1d57355d</S>
      <DT N="ModifiedDate">2019-04-10T14:33:25.283</DT>
      <B N="LastExecutedSpecified">true</B>
      <S N="Report">My Test Report</S>
      <S N="Status">The file has been saved to the "\accounting\Regional\Dues Analysis" file share.</S>
      <Obj N="Active" RefId="1">
        <TN RefId="1">
          <T>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ActiveState</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <ToString>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ActiveState</ToString>
        <Props>
          <B N="DeliveryExtensionRemoved">false</B>
          <B N="DeliveryExtensionRemovedSpecified">false</B>
          <B N="SharedDataSourceRemoved">false</B>
          <B N="SharedDataSourceRemovedSpecified">false</B>
          <B N="MissingParameterValue">false</B>
          <B N="MissingParameterValueSpecified">false</B>
          <B N="InvalidParameterValue">false</B>
          <B N="InvalidParameterValueSpecified">false</B>
          <B N="UnknownReportParameter">false</B>
          <B N="UnknownReportParameterSpecified">false</B>
        </Props>
      </Obj>
      <Nil N="VirtualPath" />
      <S N="ModifiedBy">CORPNET\CHANGEME</S>
      <S N="Description">Save in \\accounting\Regional\Dues Analysis as AVerage TEST</S>
      <DT N="LastExecuted">2021-07-01T20:36:07.327</DT>
      <Obj N="Values" RefId="2">
        <TN RefId="2">
          <T>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ParameterValue[]</T>
          <T>System.Array</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <LST>
          <Obj RefId="4">
            <TNRef RefId="3" />
            <ToString>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ParameterValue</ToString>
            <Props>
              <S N="Name">Parameter3</S>
              <S N="Value">%</S>
              <Nil N="Label" />
            </Props>
          </Obj>
        </LST>
      </Obj>
      <B N="IsDataDriven">false</B>
      <S N="Owner">CORPNET\CHANGEME</S>
      <Obj N="DeliverySettings" RefId="5">
        <TN RefId="4">
          <T>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ExtensionSettings</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <ToString>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ExtensionSettings</ToString>
        <Props>
          <S N="Extension">Report Server FileShare</S>
          <Obj N="ParameterValues" RefId="6">
            <TN RefId="5">
              <T>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ParameterValueOrFieldReference[]</T>
              <T>System.Array</T>
              <T>System.Object</T>
            </TN>
            <LST>
              <Obj RefId="7">
                <TNRef RefId="3" />
                <ToString>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ParameterValue</ToString>
                <Props>
                  <S N="Name">PATH</S>
                  <S N="Value">\\accounting\Regional\TEST</S>
                  <Nil N="Label" />
                </Props>
              </Obj>
              <Obj RefId="8">
                <TNRef RefId="3" />
                <ToString>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ParameterValue</ToString>
                <Props>
                  <S N="Name">FILENAME</S>
                  <S N="Value">TEST</S>
                  <Nil N="Label" />
                </Props>
              </Obj>
              <Obj RefId="9">
                <TNRef RefId="3" />
                <ToString>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ParameterValue</ToString>
                <Props>
                  <S N="Name">FILEEXTN</S>
                  <S N="Value">True</S>
                  <Nil N="Label" />
                </Props>
              </Obj>
              <Obj RefId="10">
                <TNRef RefId="3" />
                <ToString>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ParameterValue</ToString>
                <Props>
                  <S N="Name">USERNAME</S>
                  <S N="Value">corp\FAKE</S>
                  <Nil N="Label" />
                </Props>
              </Obj>
              <Obj RefId="11">
                <TNRef RefId="3" />
                <ToString>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ParameterValue</ToString>
                <Props>
                  <S N="Name">RENDER_FORMAT</S>
                  <S N="Value">EXCEL</S>
                  <Nil N="Label" />
                </Props>
              </Obj>
              <Obj RefId="12">
                <TNRef RefId="3" />
                <ToString>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy11er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ParameterValue</ToString>
                <Props>
                  <S N="Name">WRITEMODE</S>
                  <S N="Value">None</S>
                  <Nil N="Label" />
                </Props>
              </Obj>
            </LST>
          </Obj>
        </Props>
      </Obj>
      <S N="Path">/MY Reports/Accounting/My Test Report</S>
      <S N="MatchData">&lt;ScheduleDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt;StartDateTime xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices"&gt;2018-02-15T20:36:00.000-07:00&lt;/StartDateTime&gt;&lt;MonthlyRecurrence xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices"&gt;&lt;Days&gt;1&lt;/Days&gt;&lt;MonthsOfYear&gt;&lt;January&gt;true&lt;/January&gt;&lt;February&gt;true&lt;/February&gt;&lt;March&gt;true&lt;/March&gt;&lt;April&gt;true&lt;/April&gt;&lt;May&gt;true&lt;/May&gt;&lt;June&gt;true&lt;/June&gt;&lt;July&gt;true&lt;/July&gt;&lt;August&gt;true&lt;/August&gt;&lt;September&gt;true&lt;/September&gt;&lt;October&gt;true&lt;/October&gt;&lt;November&gt;true&lt;/November&gt;&lt;December&gt;true&lt;/December&gt;&lt;/MonthsOfYear&gt;&lt;/MonthlyRecurrence&gt;&lt;/ScheduleDefinition&gt;</S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

Comment: You're creating the file(s) with `Export-RsSubscriptionXml`? As per its own helpdoc, have you considered the corresponding `Import-RsSubscriptionXml` to later re-import the subscriptions as valid subscription objects for use with `Set-RsSubscription`?

Comment: Thanks AlwaysLearning, yes using the Import-RsSubscriptionXML was actually the first thing I tried, but I can't get it to work with Copy-RsSubscription (which is supposed to be used instead of Set-RsSubscription now, is what I understand). I posted a question on that but haven't found any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979830/failure-migrating-ssrs-subscriptions-with-multiple-paths-using-powershell-report